# Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #commodity_type"+i+"

Tags: jquery

How can I solve the following problem ?

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #commodity_type"+i+"
>
> throw new Error("Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + a)

From the following script:

```
$("#stock_request_table").on("change", ".commodity_name" + i, function () {
    var commodity_id = this.value;

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>reports/get_commodity_details/" + commodity_id + "/",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            $('#commodity_type"+i+"').val(response[0].commodity_type);

        },
        error: function (data) {

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Assuming `i` is a variable: `'#commodity_type"+i+"'` should be `'#commodity_type'+i`

Answer (score 0):

You're actually passing the string `#commodity_type"+i+"` into jQuery as a CSS selector. The trailing `+` makes that selector invalid, but in any case, you almost certainly didn't want `i` actually *in* the string; instead I assume you wanted its value.

Assuming you know that `i` will not change before the ajax response is received, you just adjust the quotes:

```
$('#commodity_type' + i).val(response[0].commodity_type);
//                ^---- string ends there, and we append i
```

If this code is in a loop where `i` may change, though, you need a value that won't change. You can use `Function#bind` to get one:

```
success: function (index, response) {
    $('#commodity_type' + index).val(response[0].commodity_type);
}.bind(null, i)
```

Note the `.bind(null, i)` at the end. `Function#bind` returns a function that, when called, will call the original function with `this` set to the first argument (we don't care about `this`, so I'm just passing `null`), then the arguments you pass `bind`, followed by the arguments the bound function was called with. So `.bind(null, i)` will take the value of `i` at that moment and use that value as the first argument when calling the original function. Then it'll be followed by the arguments jQuery gives the `success` function.